# Error when trying to redirect after dispatching an action in Redux forms

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, submit, redux-form

thats my submitTask.tsx which is a separate file

```
import React from "react";
import { SubmissionError } from "redux-form";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { addNewTask } from "../actions/Task";

const submitTask = (values: any, dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  if (!values.category || !values.description) {
    throw new SubmissionError({
      _error: "All fields are required!"
    });
  } else {
    const taskValue = {
      id: values.id,
      category: values.category,
      description: values.description,
      createdAt: values.createdAt
    };

    dispatch(addNewTask(taskValue));
    return <Redirect to="/tasks" />; //this line causing problem when i add it 
  }
};

export default submitTask;
```

here is an error message from TaskForm.tsx, did any one have any idea whats wrong here?

[image for error in VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oRor.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because functions return some value or data, not JSX.

To redirect you should try something like that:

```
myForm = () => {
    if(condition from redux store or local state){
        return <Redirect to={"/tasks"}/>
    }

    return (
        <ReduxForm onSubmit = {some function}/>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) i got the idea and tried it,  it's working thank you